# Start debug session on running node app and attach node debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I've heard a lot of rumors about being able to create a debug session on a running node application by passing `SIGUSR1` to the application.

Meaning I don't have to start an application with `node debug app.js` in order to attach a debugger to it.

How do I send `SIGUSR1` to my application and then attach a debug client to the process? It would be especially helpful if I could do this from within a Docker container with only `node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to send `SIGUSR1`

1. Use `kill -l` to view a list of signals.
2. In my case `USR1` corresponds to `10`.
3. `ps` to find the process I want to send the signal to.
4. `kill -10 <pid>`
5. A debug session is now open.

## Attaching the debugger.

1. `node debug localhost:5858`

`5858` is the default port for the legacy debugger. In `node8` sending `USR1` will activate the new `inspector` protocol, but until then this is how you can start and connect the debugger on a live application.

Watch this space for updates: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: I use StackOverflow as a note taking device occasionally when I can't find the answer online myself. I'm just filling in the gaps that the docs have for a very useful case. Hope it's helpful.